# Decoding JSON in PHP can't access the first key

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP script which successfully decodes a JSON string into a PHP object using:

```
 $amount_detail = json_decode($tuitionfee->amount_detail);
```

when I print it out, this is what I get

```
stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [amount] => 0
            [date] => 2023-01-08
            [amount_discount] => 55200
            [amount_fine] => 0
            [description] => 
            [collected_by] => Super Admin(356)
            [payment_mode] => Cash
            [received_by] => 1
            [inv_no] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [amount] => 36800
            [date] => 2023-01-08
            [description] =>  Collected By: Super Admin
            [amount_discount] => 0
            [amount_fine] => 0
            [payment_mode] => Cash
            [received_by] => 1
            [inv_no] => 2
        )

)
```

In trying to get the first object [amount_discount], I went further to do this:

```
if (is_object($amount_detail)) {
     foreach ($amount_detail as $amount_detail_key => $amount_detail_value) {
             $discount = $amount_detail_value->amount_discount;                                       
                                            }
}
```

But this is collecting data from the second key [amount_discount].
So instead of getting 55200, I'm getting 0.

How do I get to access data from the first key too?

Comment: You are _overwriting_ `$discount` in each loop iteration, so of course only the last value "survives" after the loop.

Comment: sorry, I don't get it. I get the last key even when i print this ```$amount_detail_value```. I don't think it's only about ```$discount``` or what am I missing?

Comment: _Where_ are you "printing" this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$discount` variable gets over-written each time loop is executed. So you will always get the last data.

So if you want only the first index value then use `current()`

```
$discount = current((Array)$amount_detail_value)->amount_discount;
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/8Wvqv

Note: In case you want all discount output then in your loop `echo` the `$discount` variable.